# Displaying label in same gui after button is clicked

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a program to display a label `'HI'` within the GUI, only after clicking the button `'CLICK'` within the same GUI.

My code:

```
import Tkinter as tki
class App(object):
     def __init__(self,root):
         self.root = root

         txt_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width=900, height=900)
         txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
         button3 = tki.Button(txt_frm,text="CLICK", command = self.retrieve_inpu)
         button3.grid(column=0,row=2)


     def retrieve_inpu(self):

        label = tki.Label(txt_frm,text='HI')
        label.grid(column=0,row=3)
root = tki.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

But I get error as:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Python27/teste.py", line 14, in retrieve_inpu
    label = tki.Label(txt_frm,text='HI')
NameError: global name 'txt_frm' is not defined
```

Please help me to display the label `'HI'` in the same GUI after clicking the button `'CLICK'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`txt_frm` is currently local to the `__init__` method.  In other words, there is no way to access it from outside of `__init__`.  This means that when you use it inside `retrieve_inpu`, Python will be unable to find the name and will therefore raise a `NameError`.

You can fix this problem by simply making `txt_frm` and instance attribute of `App`:

```
self.txt_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width=900, height=900)
self.txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Now, `txt_frm` is accessible through `self`, which means you can use it inside `retrieve_inpu`:

```
label = tki.Label(self.txt_frm,text='HI')
```

Comment: That's because you need to use `self.txt_frm` when you create the button too: `button3 = tki.Button(self.txt_frm, ...)`.  `txt_frm` is now an instance attribute of `App`, so it must always be accessed through `self`.